# Can i use clickOnce to deploy MS Access database?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, clickonce

i have developed an application in a `.mdb` access file with tables linked to sql server

i try toput the `mdb` file in folder shared to all user but simultaneus access break the file very often.

so iam trying to deploy the `.mdb` file to every client machine and keep it update. i have created a winform app that check `mdb` file version and copy it to a local folder and next opens the local copy

but even in this way i have problem if too many user uses the winform launcher appat same time

so iam thinking if there is a bettere and simpler way:

can i use clickonce to deploy directly the access file and create a silly webform to launch it?

i have created the webform but how can i add the `mdb` file to deploy process? i have to add it to resources? and in that case embedded or not?

and in that case how clickonce detect that the access is a modified one?

Comment: why don't you just have the users directly connect to the sql database, not to a mdb?

Comment: all forms, code and report are write with access

Comment: It might also be worth compiling your Access DB into an MDE or ACCDE (if that's still a thing).

Comment: some function does not work with mde so i have to remain with mdb :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution finally:
i add the db to Resources, setting build action to "Content", then my `program.cs` is this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        string nomeFile = @"\EW.accde";
        string DestinationPath;
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        DestinationPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + @"\Resources";

        Process.Start(DestinationPath + nomeFile);
    }
```

in this way i simply copy the new db in project and then deply app with clickonce

once installed app simply launch the database file

Comment: I like the way you solved it :-) We are on a Citrix farm. So our Ms Access application is on a network Share. When a user clicks on a .appref-ms Shortcut the Ms Access application is automatically copied to the local profile and then executed. I used your code sample to get this done.

Comment: I dont know what kind of application you used for it but I changed from Console application to Windows application. That way I dont see the Command window from the Console application so it looks Access starts on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your .mdb file is the front end to a SQL Server back end. In that case, yes, each user should have their own copy of that FE. If you do a web search, there are many solutions for distributing an Access FE, without having to re-invent the wheel. A favorite is Tony's Auto FE Updater http://autofeupdater.com/.

Comment: i read it more. i create a similar more simply tools: an exe file on shared folder that does mdb version checking but my 150 user break it every 2 days. so i don't want anything on shared locaton, so the i think about clickonce

Comment: If your users are breaking your exe, then there is something wrong with your exe. That's a good reason to not reinvent the wheel. As I stated, the autofeupdater is a popular solution. If you do a web search, you will find other solutions. Many as simple as a batch file.

Comment: with our network they break quite all they use concurrently. so i doubt that even autofeupdater put in the shared folder can end badly. now i try this: i deploy my exe with clickonce, so everyone use the installer put in shared folder only first time.