# Building a Visual studio project with access database

Tags: vb.net

Need some advice on the best way to go about this. I've finished my project and need to submit it for grading. This means it will need to be installed on the graders machine and will need to include the Access database that it's linked to.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Export the database to a DBF file.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an MS Access database with ClickOnce.

[MSDN Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx)

[ClickOnce deployment of Access database](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/24ada8b9-7a27-4e86-a16a-d6a620d216a0/clickonce-deployment-of-access-database?forum=winformssetup)

[Can i use clickOnce to deploy MS Access database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069589/can-i-use-clickonce-to-deploy-ms-access-database)